# Motorcycles, bikes, motorbikes, mopeds, motorcyclists, bikers, and motorbikers in AE

Tags: american-english, vocabulary, word-usage

As far as I know, "motorcycle" is the formal term -- and "bike" the informal one --  for a powered two (and occasionally three) wheeled vehicle resembling a bike but larger, heavier, and a heap more powerful, chiefly for one rider but sometimes having two saddles and a sidecar for passengers.

Besides, motorcycle riders are referred to fornally as "motorcyclists", and informally as "bikers".

Now, "motorbike" is the generic term for a lightweight, less powerful motorcycle with a smaller frame.

The thing is " motorbike" can both designate a lightweight motorbike (which I roughly equate with a dirt or pit bike stylewise), and also a pedal bicycle propelled by an attached motor (which, I guess, looks more or less like a moped).

Hence my question: how does what you Americans call a motorbike differ from a dirt (or pit) bike style vehicle, and from a moped?

Also, if "motorcyclist" and "biker" are both specific terms to refer to a motorcycle rider, what do you call someone that rides a motorbike? A motorbiker, or something else?

> http://www.thefreedictionary.com/motorcycle
>
> http://www.thefreedictionary.com/motorbike
>
> http://www.thefreedictionary.com/minibike
>
> http://www.thefreedictionary.com/moped

Comment: This is a good question!  A motorbike vs. a dirt bike is differentiated by where you intend to ride it.  A moped is a small motorbike that is pedaled to start it up.

Comment: I am a US speaker, and I have never encountered this use of *motorbike* to designate a class of motorcycle. In my experience, *motorbike* and *bike* are just colloquialisms for motorcycles of all kinds. For some speakers they may even embrace mopeds.

Comment: @StoneyB Motorbike is usually a smaller motorcycle, but bigger than a moped.  [See this](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/motorbike)

Comment: You may find this link helpful [Types of Motorcycles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_motorcycles)  The gist of the article is that most of the designations are made by size, intent of use, and legal designations.

Comment: If by "lightweight motorcycle" you mean something like a Vespa, they're normally called "scooters", at least in Southern AE. "Motorbike" *may* be a legal classification, but people around here don't *say* it. For other types, they all just get lumped in with dirt bikes. Or, just "bikes".

Comment: @Geobits By "lightweight motorcycle" I have in mind the "dirt bike style" ones that you can find in urban areas. "Scooters" are called likewise in France, and they indeed belong to the "motorbike" category.

Comment: @DavidM That article does not offer 'motorbike' as a type. I've been searching Google for half an hour looking for some reliable source making this distinction and haven't found one yet. I wonder if perhaps the real distinction isn't sociolectal: what kind of bike is likely to be owned by a speaker who refers to his machine as a 'motorbike'?

Comment: @StoneyB I'm not sure.  I've always heard the distinction as a size thing.  I can't find a real distinctive source either.  But, motorbike = dirt bike to my brain, it's just the tires and the shocks that are different.

Comment: "a pedal bicycle propelled by an attached motor" I don't know about the U.S. but in Australia this would be called "a motorised bicycle".

Comment: @Neil Yeah, I'm not sure the category has a proper name.  But, that sounds right to me.  As opposed to a moped which I believe has pedals as part of its starter system.

Comment: @Neil In France this would be called a "cyclomoteur" (cyclomotor) or, more commonly, by the trade name Solex.

Comment: @DavidM This is what I would call a moped http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VéloSoleX. Can it also be called a motorbike in the US?

Comment: @NourishedGourmet It would be a moped for us, too.  I think there is not a particularly well developed discrimination between the classes, though.  Motorbike is a bit more on the order of dirt bike for me.

Comment: The best place for this would be a biking enthus' Q&A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does what Americans call a motorbike differ from a dirt (or pit) bike style vehicle, and from a moped?

In my experience, mopeds are much more popular in Canada than the US. Having said that, (AmE here) I would say a moped was a rider-assisted lightweight motorbike intended for on-road use. A motorbike and dirt bike would differ by how they were conformed for their specific use: a dirt bike could be powerful but lightweight, have different suspension and tires than a motorbike (better known as a motorscooter) for street use. We often simply call these "bikes" when the context is already known (*nice bike* / that's a *cute bike*; I'd like one of those.)

> If "motorcyclist" and "biker" are both specific terms to refer to a motorcycle rider, what do you call someone that rides a motorbike? A motorbiker, or something else?

Speaking as an average American (that is, I don't drive a motorcycle, but have three family members who do/did), a *biker* is reserved for a serious motorbike sports enthusiast, or a serious motorcyclist, with at least a very sweet (i.e. expensive/powerful) motorcycle that they ride either as a serious hobby (e.g. every weekend, and going to conventions, gatherings, etc.) or a true biker of old, think *Easy Rider* (or if that's way too far back for you, *Sons of Anarchy*.) (Then there are always the biker wannabes.) AFAIK, we don't have one specific designation for a lightweight bike user; *he rides a motorcycle to work...*. That's it from this little part of the world.